# Не удается повторно вызвать метод рисования линий с другими координатами

Tags: python, tkinter

В tkinter Не удается повторно вызвать метод `draw_lines()` с другими координатами. При этом печатаются они повторным вызовом метода `printing()` без проблем. Не могу понять, почему? Если использовать функцию рисования вне класса, все вызывается  и работает. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas


class DrawLines():
    def __init__(self, master):
               
        self.canv_1 = Canvas(master, width=400, height=250)
        self.canv_1.grid(column=0, row=0)
        
        self.line_1 = [249, 120, 150, 10]
        self.line_2 = [0, 120, 150, 210]
               
        self.printing(self.line_1)
        self.printing(self.line_2)
               
        self.draw_lines(self.line_1)
        self.draw_lines(self.line_2)
       
    def printing(self, a):
        print('Printing ', a)

    def draw_lines(self, line_1):
        self.canv_1.create_line(self.line_1[0],
                                self.line_1[1],
                                self.line_1[2],
                                self.line_1[3])


root = Tk()
dl = DrawLines(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в методе `draw_lines` координаты берутся не из параметра метода `line_1`, а из поля объекта `self.line_1`. Нужно убрать `self` (и чтобы не путаться лучше переименовать параметр, так чтобы имя не совпадало с именем поля объекта):

```
def draw_lines(self, line):
    self.canv_1.create_line(line[0],
                            line[1],
                            line[2],
                            line[3])
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за очень оперативный ответ. Заработало. Где бы еще про это почитать?

Comment: @ErshovYuri, в данном случае главное запомнить, что обращение через self - это обращение к полю или методу объекта. Для обращения к параметрам метода, локальным или глобальным переменным self не нужно. А так в любом учебнике/самоучителе по Python про классы и объекты можно почитать.

Comment: еще раз большое спасибо.